# What does node class do in LinkedList class

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how is Java creating nodes i.e. making linked list.So I was checking the LinkedList.java file and I saw  a inner node class in linked list class so is this inner node class responsible for actually creating the nodes?

Also when we use this class will we say that object created is for LinkedList Class or for Node Class?

```
 public class LinkedList<E>
  extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
  implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
  {

private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;
    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

P.S It is not a duplicate I am trying to understand what is node class doing in the built in LinkedList class which is a double linked list .In the other question they are creating a new singly linked list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innner `Node` class is not *responsible for creating* the nodes. It **is** the node, or actually it represents a node in the linked list. Since items can be anything and the `LinkedList` *wants* to link the items (know what is before and what is next each item) it needs the `Node` abstraction to keep the item and that information.

[image]

So `LinkedList` creates the nodes and connects them. It keeps a pointer to the first and last of those nodes to manage the connections and avoid going in circles when iterating.

Comment: That part I understand but my problem is I cant find any calls  to the Node Class with the prev and next index in the LinkedList Class

Comment: Are you looking at the source of `LinkedList`? Because if you are it's hard to miss those references and I'm probably not understanding you. If you look a `LinkedList` source you can clearly see `new Node<>(...)` and uses of `first` and `last`. Search for the typical `add` method and then see the `linkLast` which is called. That method contains all the cases.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for .Thank you .Can you tell me one more thing in linkLast we have         `final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);` so this newNode object is a object of Node class?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you are not using an IDE I recommend you do. Eclipse is a popular option. If you use a Java IDE like Eclipse you can Ctrl+click or simply hover your mouse and see what each element refers to. That feature makes relations like these evident.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is a linear data structure where each element is a separate object. Each element (we will call it a node) of a list is comprises of the data and a reference to the next node and previous node. The last node has a reference to null.

Each element in a linked list is node,which actually holds the data ,previous and next references.

**Since the linked list supports reference to the next element we need to have a node which holds data and references as well.**

refer [Linked List](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html)

Comment: I actually would support your answer, but please be aware that your answer is not in line with the question. In the question, we have two links, `prev` and `next`. So each `Node` has three items.

Comment: I am sorry but I never asked for help in basic data structure.I want to understand how is Node class working in the built in Linkedlist Class

Answer (score 1):

This kind of implementation is mainly because of preservation of the `Node` within a `LinkedList` or increased encapsulation.

Basically Inner classes (here Node class) are used especially when that class has no other use other than using inside another single class.

for example, In this implementation Node is declared as an inner class because the node can exist only in a linked list. without linked list a single node will be of no use.

And this Node class can only be instantiated right after instantiation of linked list. Thus, this supports the concept that **No node can exist without a linked list**.

So typically this `LinkedList` and Node are bound together so that `Node` couldnt exist without creating a `LinkedList`